# What happens to the term $e^{j2wt}$ as phasors are multiplied

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

When working with phasors we have $\bar{Z} = Acos(wt + \phi) = Re(Ae^{j(wt + \phi)}) = Re(Ae^{j\phi}e^{jwt})$ where $\bar{P}_1 = Ae^{j\phi}$ is the phasor.

But when we multiply $\bar{Z_{1, \phi}}$ and $\bar{Z_{2, \alpha}}$ we should have $Re(A_1e^{j\phi}e^{jwt}) \times Re(A_2e^{j\alpha}e^{jwt}) = Re(A_1A_2e^{j(\phi + \alpha)}e^{j2wt})$ where $\bar{S} = A_1A_2e^{j(\phi + \alpha)}$ is the phasor of the sum, but we now have the argument $e^{j2wt}$ instead of $e^{jwt}$ which would mean the frequency of the signal is now doubled - which is not the case for an electric circuit.

What tutors and articles I've seen doing is to ignore the mathematical approach and focus on the phasor domain calculations. But I want the mathematical approach in order to understand what is happening underneath. The resultant sinusoid should be $\bar{S} = A_1A_2cos(2wt + \phi + \alpha)$ which is not the correct result we have on a circuit. So what am I misinterpreting here?